# How to create a plugin with automatic update?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, automatic-updates, virus

I'm developing a plugin and would like to know how do I send automatic updates to it? Do I have to use webhooks for this?

The plugin will be for private use, it will scan the website to remove malware, however there is always the possibility of creating new malware outside of those that are already included in the removal list.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean actual plugin updates or updates to data that the plugin stores? The easiest way will be to publish the current version number and dataset on your own server, and then set up a wp_cron job or similar in the plugin that fetch the latest version number from your server and compares it against the version number it has stored.

Comment: Perfect thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this plugin might help

https://wordpress.org/plugins/gitium/